# For loop to monitor sites not loading

Tags: bash, for-loop, curl, pipe

I manage a large number of sites and wanted to find an inexpensive way to make myself aware when one of those sites aren't loading to minimize the number of times customers are finding their sites are down before me. I've decided to create a for loop to load the domain names and output the domains that return anything other than a 200 response. Could anyone help me with the syntax? I'm not sure how to do this.

So far I believe it's: `for i in $; do curl -L $;`

Past what I have above I'm not sure how to get the response to a file that I'll check each day for domains.

Anything you can offer would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome  to Stackoveflow, MsMcMiller! Could you edit your post using the markdown so that the code is properly formatted? It is enough to have it on a separate line with 4 space of indentation.

Did you try your approach? What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

You could define this bash function:

```
httpstatus() {
    file=$1

    # read file line by line
    while IFS= read -r site; do

        # print sites that do not return status 20X or 30X
        if [[ $(curl -o /dev/null -sIw '%{http_code}\n' $site) != [23]0[0-2] ]]; then
            echo $site
        fi

    done < "$file"
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$ cat sites
https://stackoverflow.com
https://example.com
https://example.com/returns-404
$ httpstatus sites
https://example.com/returns-404
```

Bash syntax and builtin commands are documented in `man bash`.  [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) is other helpful resource.